# Wrong contents appearing in .bashrc and .bash_profile files in the ~/ directory instead of the expected user environment variables and values

Tags: bash, terminal

I am currently in the **~/** directory in terminal on my Mac, and trying to configure the .bash_profile.

I am trying to issue the **cat** command to view its contents. The result is the following:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK. if [ -f '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud. if [ -f '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"
```

I receive the following when I try to view the .bashrc file:

```
if [ -f '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/iwill/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```

Any ideas why am I not seeing the user environment variables as I should be ?

Comment: Is that formatting right? Is `.bash_profile` really just two commented lines?

Comment: Is the `if` really on the same line as `# The next line...`? or is that a copying error?

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the environment variables you want to see are in `~/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc` and `.bashrc` loads it.